# How to make a .NET program connect to a PHP script?

Tags: php, .net

Hello i need help with this, im trying to make a .NET program connect to a php script. Basicly make it send like a request saying "hello world" or something on the php site from the .NET program.

Please i need help with understanding how i can communicate with the .NET Framework or the other way around.

Thanks in advance,
John

Comment: Based on your question I'm going to say you know nothing about .Net or php so you've got a lot of tutorials to read before you are ready for either.

Comment: .net desktop app, control line, asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you mean by connecting .Net with PHP.
But, you can try the PHP compiler for .Net (www.php-compiler.net or http://phalanger.codeplex.com/).
Good luck